# VM cannot connect to internet

Tags: virtualbox

I am currently making use of virtualbox. My host is an ubuntu machine, as well as my guest. For some reason, my guest cannot connect to the internet. As like most posts I have seen on the internet, I have set my network adapter to NAT through virtual box.

I have tried everything I have seen on the internet, but no luck. Can anybody please give me any ideas on how I can solve this issue please?

The version I am currently using is qt 4.1.18. I downloaded it from the ubuntu software centre.

I have also tried installing another virtual machine, but neither does this have internet. (Set to NAT like the previous). Is it fair to assume that the problem is on the host side? Obviously, on the host I DO have internet.

As for the adapter type, I am making use of Intel PRO/1000 MT desktop.

Furthermore, the host connects to the internet through a wireless adapter

Comment: Please post the output of `ifconfig` inside the virtual machine, so that we know how does Ubuntu see the virtual network interface. Post the output of `ping -c 3 10.0.2.2`, so that we know whether Ubuntu can ping the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day and a half working on solving this problem, I finally found a turn around.

First I did a format of ubuntu (thanks to ubuntu this didnt take much time)

Rather than installing virtualbox from the ubuntu software centre, I downloaded a newer version from virtualbox.org. It in a .deb format and therefore was very easy to install

Next, I installed a guest vm with ubuntu, and managed to connect to the internet :)

I still have no clue why it initially did not work. Maybe the older version available on in the software centre has some kind of bug. However, I was not able to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

You should add more info about your hardware and network, but you can try using bridged connection to your eth0 interface (or whatever you use) with PCnet-Fast III.

Comment: what kind of info are you looking for? I know my question is a little bit vague, but I honestly dont know where to start from. All the possible solutions I found on the internet did not work.

Comment: Can you add new computers to your network, what type of network card you use, version of virtualbox, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Out of desperation I have solved this issue by creating two adapters n my virtual machines.
The first attached to bridged adapter, wlan0, PCNET Fast III
The second attached to NAT, Intel pro 1000

It now works so I won't be touching it...

Comment: you got this problem because you installed virtual box from the ubuntu software centre?

Comment: No I was using the one from virtualbox site